# Set css style on click and remove them on click

Tags: css, onclick, styles

I want to set style when I click on div. I done this, It's work. But I want when its clicked and when I click to set the default style.

```
     $('#tray-button').click(function() {
       $('.buttons-content').css('bottom', '160px');
    });

 <div class="buttons-content">
        <div id="tray-button" class="button">
            <div class="white"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-grip-horizontal"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="white"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="button play-pause play">
            <div class="white"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <i class="far fa-1-1x  fa-play-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="button rotate">
            <div class="white"></div>
            <div class="black"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-expand-alt"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

buttons-content - default bottom: 40;

1. When click on #tray-button -> bottom: 160px;
2. When click again on #tray-button -> bottom: 40px; (default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a specific CSS rule e.g.

```
.buttons-content.toggled {
   bottom: 160px;
}
```

with a `.toggled` class and on `click` toggle that class

```
$('#tray-button').click(function() {
   $('.buttons-content').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

When the class is removed the style of the element will be automatically reset to the previous state. Furthermore your script is more mantainable because the style is not hardcoded within.

Answer (score 0):

this script just remembers the last state and does whatever you want.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var stack = 0
$("#tray-button").click(function()
{
if (stack === 0){
}
$('.buttons-content').css('bottom', '160px');
stack = 1;
}else{
$('.buttons-content').css('bottom', '40px');
stack = 0;
}

});
```